# Цвет текста элементов списка при наведении

Tags: html, css

У меня цвет текста меняется, если наводить непосредственно на сам текст. Как сделать, чтобы цвет менялся при наведении на любое место поля?

```css
.sidebar_left_menu_nav {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li {
 padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
 width: 130px; 
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #728796;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li:hover {
 background-color: #728796; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar_left_menu_nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае, вам нужно или стилизовать ссылку, а не `li`:

```css
.sidebar_left_menu_nav {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #728796;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
 width: 130px; 
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav a:hover {
 background-color: #728796; 
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar_left_menu_nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Или отлавливать наведение на `li`, а не на `a`

```css
.sidebar_left_menu_nav {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li {
 padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
 width: 130px; 
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #728796;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li:hover a {
 color: #fff;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li:hover {
 background-color: #728796; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar_left_menu_nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось.

Comment: @Таня, если вам помог мой ответ, проголосуйте за него и отметьте, пожалуйста, верным.

Answer (score 2):

Нам понадобится конструкция такого вида `li:hover a` т.е. значит что при наведении на `li` совершать действия с `a`

```css
.sidebar_left_menu_nav {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 12px;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li {
 padding: 5px 0px 10px 5px;
 width: 130px; 
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #728796;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li:hover {
 background-color: #728796; 
}
.sidebar_left_menu_nav li:hover a { 
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar_left_menu_nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```